# Need dataset with multiple subdivisions filtered down to limited half-integer range before charting

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

Please see below for dataset and desirable visual.

I just need some guidance/path in constructing a data model and subsequent visuals for the following dataset.

I have various Vessel Names, divided into Test Dates, divided into Operating Mode, then Side of Vessel, then Handle Position, Nominal Speed, Plane of Measurement, then finally, Order (of vibration frequency).

From each of these subdivisions of [Vessel->.....->[Plane], I need to round [Orders] to nearest half-integers (x.5), then filter down to only those Orders that are **nearest** to each {0.5, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0}.

The resulting half-integers between 0.5 and 3.0 will be my Chart Series (in excel terms) plotted on a [Velocity] vs [Nominal Speed] scatter/line chart.

- Should I construct a different Table Expression for each filtered set? (Axial Plane of 950 rpm Nominal Speed of Port Side of James Vessel)
- ....Then allocate every one of those sets to the "Values" of a chart?

I don't really know where to begin.

| Vessel | Date | Mode | Side | Plane | Handle Position | Nominal Speed, rpm | Actual Speed, rpm | Overall, in/sec | Velocity, in/sec | Frequency, cpm | Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 5 | 500 | 512.7 | 0.177 | 0.046 | 769.0 | 1.54 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 5 | 500 | 512.7 | 0.177 | 0.058 | 1025.4 | 2.05 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 5 | 500 | 512.7 | 0.177 | 0.157 | 1281.7 | 2.56 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 5 | 500 | 512.7 | 0.177 | 0.008 | 1538.1 | 3.08 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 5 | 500 | 512.7 | 0.177 | 0.007 | 1794.4 | 3.59 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 5 | 500 | 505.4 | 0.177 | 0.019 | 2526.9 | 5.05 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 5 | 500 | 488.3 | 0.177 | 0.008 | 5127.0 | 10.25 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 5 | 500 | 502.1 | 0.177 | 0.008 | 17321.8 | 34.64 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 5 | 500 | 501.3 | 0.177 | 0.009 | 17797.9 | 35.60 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 5 | 500 | 498.5 | 0.177 | 0.009 | 17944.3 | 35.89 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 6 | 589 | 586.0 | 0.291 | 0.048 | 1171.9 | 1.99 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 6 | 589 | 659.2 | 0.291 | 0.036 | 1318.4 | 2.24 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 6 | 589 | 556.6 | 0.291 | 0.033 | 1391.6 | 2.36 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 6 | 589 | 600.6 | 0.291 | 0.033 | 1501.5 | 2.55 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 6 | 589 | 629.9 | 0.291 | 0.023 | 1574.7 | 2.67 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 6 | 589 | 585.9 | 0.291 | 0.019 | 1757.8 | 2.98 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 6 | 589 | 593.3 | 0.291 | 0.023 | 2966.3 | 5.04 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 6 | 589 | 592.0 | 0.291 | 0.023 | 3552.2 | 6.03 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 6 | 589 | 590.5 | 0.291 | 0.019 | 4724.1 | 8.02 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 6 | 589 | 591.4 | 0.291 | 0.019 | 7983.4 | 13.55 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 7 | 675 | 695.8 | 0.191 | 0.060 | 695.8 | 1.03 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 7 | 675 | 683.6 | 0.191 | 0.079 | 1025.4 | 1.52 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 7 | 675 | 677.5 | 0.191 | 0.080 | 1355.0 | 2.01 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 7 | 675 | 673.8 | 0.191 | 0.083 | 1684.6 | 2.50 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 7 | 675 | 683.6 | 0.191 | 0.037 | 2050.8 | 3.04 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 7 | 675 | 674.9 | 0.191 | 0.032 | 4724.1 | 7.00 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 7 | 675 | 678.7 | 0.191 | 0.030 | 5090.3 | 7.54 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 7 | 675 | 677.5 | 0.191 | 0.052 | 6774.9 | 10.04 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 7 | 675 | 680.1 | 0.191 | 0.033 | 7141.1 | 10.58 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 7 | 675 | 674.4 | 0.191 | 0.032 | 8093.3 | 11.99 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 8 | 810 | 805.7 | 0.732 | 0.159 | 1208.5 | 1.49 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 8 | 810 | 805.7 | 0.732 | 0.149 | 1611.3 | 1.99 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 8 | 810 | 805.7 | 0.732 | 0.168 | 2014.2 | 2.49 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 8 | 810 | 805.7 | 0.732 | 0.310 | 4028.3 | 4.97 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 8 | 810 | 809.3 | 0.732 | 0.150 | 8093.3 | 9.99 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 8 | 810 | 808.7 | 0.732 | 0.109 | 9704.6 | 11.98 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 8 | 810 | 808.6 | 0.732 | 0.241 | 10107.4 | 12.48 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 8 | 810 | 808.3 | 0.732 | 0.115 | 11315.9 | 13.97 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 8 | 810 | 808.2 | 0.732 | 0.228 | 11718.8 | 14.47 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 8 | 810 | 808.1 | 0.732 | 0.384 | 12121.6 | 14.96 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 9 | 960 | 988.8 | 0.514 | 0.080 | 988.8 | 1.03 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 9 | 960 | 976.5 | 0.514 | 0.323 | 1464.8 | 1.53 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 9 | 960 | 974.1 | 0.514 | 0.222 | 4870.6 | 5.07 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 9 | 960 | 972.1 | 0.514 | 0.108 | 5346.7 | 5.57 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 9 | 960 | 971.7 | 0.514 | 0.083 | 7287.6 | 7.59 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 9 | 960 | 939.2 | 0.514 | 0.097 | 7983.4 | 8.32 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 9 | 960 | 973.7 | 0.514 | 0.074 | 8276.4 | 8.62 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 9 | 960 | 972.5 | 0.514 | 0.076 | 8752.4 | 9.12 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 9 | 960 | 974.4 | 0.514 | 0.151 | 11206.1 | 11.67 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 9 | 960 | 973.1 | 0.514 | 0.085 | 13623.0 | 14.19 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 10 | 1175 | 1171.9 | 0.423 | 0.293 | 1171.9 | 1.00 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 10 | 1175 | 1171.9 | 0.423 | 0.066 | 1757.8 | 1.50 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 10 | 1175 | 1171.9 | 0.423 | 0.068 | 2343.8 | 1.99 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 10 | 1175 | 1171.9 | 0.423 | 0.068 | 2929.7 | 2.49 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 10 | 1175 | 1171.9 | 0.423 | 0.136 | 4687.5 | 3.99 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 10 | 1175 | 1179.2 | 0.423 | 0.136 | 5896.0 | 5.02 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 10 | 1175 | 1177.1 | 0.423 | 0.101 | 8239.7 | 7.01 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 10 | 1175 | 1176.2 | 0.423 | 0.078 | 9997.6 | 8.51 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 10 | 1175 | 1174.9 | 0.423 | 0.063 | 14099.1 | 12.00 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Cruise | Port | Axial | 10 | 1175 | 1177.7 | 0.423 | 0.060 | 14721.7 | 12.53 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 5 | 950 | 952.1 | 0.257 | 0.062 | 1428.2 | 1.50 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 5 | 950 | 952.1 | 0.257 | 0.121 | 4760.7 | 5.01 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 5 | 950 | 952.2 | 0.257 | 0.059 | 6189.0 | 6.51 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 5 | 950 | 952.1 | 0.257 | 0.053 | 7141.1 | 7.52 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 5 | 950 | 952.2 | 0.257 | 0.107 | 9521.5 | 10.02 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 5 | 950 | 952.1 | 0.257 | 0.055 | 10473.6 | 11.02 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 5 | 950 | 952.1 | 0.257 | 0.052 | 10949.7 | 11.53 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 5 | 950 | 952.2 | 0.257 | 0.063 | 11901.9 | 12.53 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 5 | 950 | 952.1 | 0.257 | 0.063 | 14282.2 | 15.03 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 5 | 950 | 952.2 | 0.257 | 0.056 | 17138.7 | 18.04 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 6 | 950 | 952.1 | 0.245 | 0.031 | 952.1 | 1.00 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 6 | 950 | 952.1 | 0.245 | 0.063 | 1428.2 | 1.50 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 6 | 950 | 952.1 | 0.245 | 0.097 | 4760.7 | 5.01 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 6 | 950 | 952.2 | 0.245 | 0.049 | 6189.0 | 6.51 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 6 | 950 | 952.2 | 0.245 | 0.098 | 9521.5 | 10.02 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 6 | 950 | 952.1 | 0.245 | 0.058 | 10473.6 | 11.02 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 6 | 950 | 952.1 | 0.245 | 0.044 | 10949.7 | 11.53 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 6 | 950 | 952.2 | 0.245 | 0.057 | 11901.9 | 12.53 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 6 | 950 | 954.6 | 0.245 | 0.070 | 14318.8 | 15.07 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 6 | 950 | 954.2 | 0.245 | 0.031 | 17175.3 | 18.08 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 7 | 970 | 830.1 | 0.267 | 0.053 | 1245.1 | 1.28 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 7 | 970 | 976.5 | 0.267 | 0.143 | 1464.8 | 1.51 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 7 | 970 | 970.5 | 0.267 | 0.053 | 1940.9 | 2.00 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 7 | 970 | 966.8 | 0.267 | 0.094 | 4834.0 | 4.98 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 7 | 970 | 969.0 | 0.267 | 0.059 | 6298.8 | 6.49 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 7 | 970 | 966.8 | 0.267 | 0.047 | 7251.0 | 7.48 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 7 | 970 | 970.5 | 0.267 | 0.082 | 7763.7 | 8.00 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 7 | 970 | 971.3 | 0.267 | 0.056 | 11169.4 | 11.51 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 7 | 970 | 970.5 | 0.267 | 0.049 | 13586.4 | 14.01 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 7 | 970 | 968.0 | 0.267 | 0.045 | 17907.7 | 18.46 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 8 | 1110 | 1098.6 | 0.280 | 0.107 | 1098.6 | 0.99 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 8 | 1110 | 1098.6 | 0.280 | 0.052 | 1647.9 | 1.48 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 8 | 1110 | 1098.7 | 0.280 | 0.094 | 2197.3 | 1.98 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 8 | 1110 | 1107.8 | 0.280 | 0.061 | 4431.2 | 3.99 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 8 | 1110 | 1106.0 | 0.280 | 0.128 | 5529.8 | 4.98 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 8 | 1110 | 1104.7 | 0.280 | 0.073 | 6628.4 | 5.97 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 8 | 1110 | 1103.9 | 0.280 | 0.083 | 7727.1 | 6.96 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 8 | 1110 | 1103.5 | 0.280 | 0.063 | 8276.4 | 7.46 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 8 | 1110 | 1107.2 | 0.280 | 0.061 | 9411.6 | 8.48 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 8 | 1110 | 1105.3 | 0.280 | 0.049 | 18237.3 | 16.43 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 9 | 1247 | 1245.1 | 0.297 | 0.093 | 1867.7 | 1.50 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 9 | 1247 | 1245.1 | 0.297 | 0.068 | 2490.2 | 2.00 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 9 | 1247 | 1245.1 | 0.297 | 0.066 | 4357.9 | 3.49 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 9 | 1247 | 1245.1 | 0.297 | 0.107 | 4980.5 | 3.99 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 9 | 1247 | 1245.1 | 0.297 | 0.072 | 5603.0 | 4.49 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 9 | 1247 | 1245.1 | 0.297 | 0.135 | 6225.6 | 4.99 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 9 | 1247 | 1238.5 | 0.297 | 0.070 | 7430.7 | 5.96 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 9 | 1247 | 1249.4 | 0.297 | 0.056 | 10620.1 | 8.52 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 9 | 1247 | 1249.0 | 0.297 | 0.068 | 11865.2 | 9.51 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 9 | 1247 | 1248.0 | 0.297 | 0.098 | 15600.6 | 12.51 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 10 | 1306 | 1318.4 | 0.300 | 0.069 | 659.2 | 0.50 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 10 | 1306 | 1293.9 | 0.300 | 0.091 | 1940.9 | 1.49 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 10 | 1306 | 1300.1 | 0.300 | 0.063 | 2600.1 | 1.99 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 10 | 1306 | 1293.9 | 0.300 | 0.053 | 3881.8 | 2.97 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 10 | 1306 | 1297.4 | 0.300 | 0.118 | 4541.0 | 3.48 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 10 | 1306 | 1300.1 | 0.300 | 0.121 | 5200.2 | 3.98 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 10 | 1306 | 1296.4 | 0.300 | 0.118 | 6481.9 | 4.96 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 10 | 1306 | 1300.1 | 0.300 | 0.075 | 7800.3 | 5.97 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 10 | 1306 | 1297.8 | 0.300 | 0.064 | 16223.1 | 12.42 |
| James | 3/24/2023 | Dual Engine | Port | Axial | 10 | 1306 | 1303.7 | 0.300 | 0.053 | 16296.4 | 12.48 |

[Excel ScatterPlot to Replicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfBA8.png)

I may just go in blindly and try to construct separate CALCULATETABLE(FILTER(ALL measures for each division of [Vessel] down to its [Plane]s. Then try to drop these into a Line/Scatterplot's Values.

Comment: Can explain a bit more "round [Orders] to nearest half-integers (x.5), then filter down to only those Orders that are nearest to each {0.5, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0}." please. What do you mean by "nearest to each"? If Order is 2.9 -> 3.0 ✅, if Order is 3.4 -> 3.5 ❌

Comment: @SamNseir Within each subset of eg. 
[James->Cruise->Port->900rpm->Axial->Orders],

there may be multiple values which round to a particular half-integer, eg.
{0.49,0.53,0.55} all round to ->0.5.

I would only like to filter for 0.49, then subsequently in the next column, 0.49 will be rounded to and become the usable 0.50.

Comment: @SamNseir Since 0.49 is nearest to 0.50 among those 3 values that are all within rounding range to 0.50.

Comment: Got it, thanks. And what's the formula for the Y-axis (displacement amplitude)?

Comment: @SamNseir Oh, sorry. That chart is supposed to be a Velocity chart. Velocity on Y-Axis.    Vessel | Date | Side | Mode | Handle Position | Nominal Speed | Plane.    If there are no other values that match a common half-integer, those would all "become" their rounded half-integers. 0.49->0.5; 0.98->1.0: 1.47->1.5

Comment: A couple more. 1. Help define the exact subset, Is it Vessel | Mode | Side | Plane | Nominal Speed ? What about Date and Handle Position? And 2. If we have [ 0.49, 0.98, 1.47] for a subset, would you expect only 1 from these or all 3 (since each matches a different half int)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm hoping I understood your need. Try the following.

Create the following Calculated Columns in order:

```
Order Group = 
  var mr = MROUND([Order], .5)
  RETURN IF(0.5 <= mr && mr <= 3, mr)


Order diff =
  IF( NOT ISBLANK([Order Group]), ABS([Order Group] - [Order]) )


Order Chart = 
  var gpSubset = [Vessel] & [Date] & [Mode] & [Side] & [Handle Position] & [Nominal Speed, rpm] & [Plane] & [Order Group]
  var gpFilter = FILTER(ALL('Data'), (gpSubset = [Vessel] & [Date] & [Mode] & [Side] & [Handle Position] & [Nominal Speed, rpm] & [Plane] & [Order Group]) && NOT ISBLANK([Order Group]) )
  var minDiff = CALCULATE(MINX(gpFilter, [Order diff]))
  RETURN IF([Order diff] = minDiff, [Order Group])
```

See if this gives you what you are after.